# Getting error "auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key" when implementing Firebase signup

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am creating a mobile application using React Native and Expo Go with Firebase authentication. I tried to implement signup / signin, and when I try to login in from my iPhone from the Expo Go app, I get the error "auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key".

Here is the code for signup:

```
export const signup = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    console.log("Auth: ", auth);
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log("User created: ", user);
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.error("Error signing up: ", errorCode, errorMessage);
        throw error;
        // ..
    });
};
```

And here is the code for firebase initialization:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
  };


const initializeFirebase = () => {
    if (!getApps().length) {
        initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } else {
        getApp(); // if already initialized, use that one
    }
};

export default initializeFirebase;
```

`initializeFirebase` is called from my App.tsx component.

I have seen other questions and answers regarding the same error, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I know that the API-key is not the problem, as it works to update data in Firebase Realtime database with that same API-key.

UPDATE:

I tried to run the Expo application from my web browser so I can see the API calls that are performed, and I noticed that the query parameter "key" for the signup call looks like this: %22{FIREBASE_API_KEY}%22%2C.
[image: SignUp - API call]

And when I run the same call from Postman, but remove the %22 and %2C, it works better, but now I get the ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION - error message. Possibly because the call is from within Postman / I have not enabled the "Anonymous" sign-in provider in the Firebase Console?

My question now is why are %22 and %2C added to the key in the API-call, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved this one myself. For anyone else with the same problem:
It seems the issue with my code was with how my .env file stored the variables.
My .env file looked like this:

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY: "API_KEY",
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
...
```

But what fixed my issue, was removing the quotes and commas from the .env - file (I am pretty new to .env files so do not know why the quotes would be an issue) like so:

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY: API_KEY
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: AUTH_DOMAIN
...
```

It is not clear for me why the calls to update / read from the Realtime Database did not complain about wrong API-key, but at least, this fixed the issue with Authentication.